# Give a 7 days grace period for paypal subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am setting up paypal subscriptions on my system and i want to give my subscribers a grace period of 7 days before i start charging them.

Is this possible with paypal subscriptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to give the client a trial subscription period.

You can use the 'period1' parameter. Per PayPal: "(optional) Trial subscription interval in days, weeks, months, years (example: a four-day interval is "period1: 4 D")".

See here:

[Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Variables](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside)

[ASP.NET PayPal Subscriptions IPN](http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much. From Ireland myself. Bout time we have some representatives